# request.env['omniauth.params'] null using devise_token_auth gem for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I'm implementing a social login feature through my API using the devise_token_auth gem available [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth). I am, however, getting a problem with the following gem controller also available [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb), specifically line 14, having no content in the request.env['omniauth.params'] variable.

My client application omniauth.rb configurations are as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'CCCCCC', 'CCCCCC', info_fields: 'email,id,name,link, first_name, last_name'
  provider :google_oauth2, 'CCCCCCCCC', 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCC', scope: 'email,profile,plus.me', image_aspect_ratio: 'square', image_size: 48, access_type: 'online', name: 'google'
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://localhost:3000"
end
```

(localhost:3000 being the API URL)

These are my configurations in the facebook developer's console:

/settings
[image]

/facebook login
[image]

these are my API routes:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
```

and this is the error output in the server command window:

```
  Parameters: {"code"=>"XXXXXXXXX...XXXXXXXXXX", "state"=>"YYYYY...YYYYY", "provider"=>"facebook"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/devise_token_auth-162967970c95/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:14:in `redirect_callbacks'
```

Note: if I get the "Users" resource out of the "api/v1/" namescope, the error is not same (I can update this if someone feels it's relevant)

I would appreciate if someone could explain how I solve this issue and why I am running into it.

I'm happy to provide more information regarding this.